# What I am missing here (Hibernate begin transaction)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a test class :

```
 class SomeTest {
       public static void main(String args[]){
       Client kom = new Client();
       kom.setId(kom.newID());
       kom.setClient("OldName");
       SessionFactory sessionFactory =  new    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
       Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
          session.save(kom); // I think insert is here ?
          Query q = session.createSQLQuery(" call change_name(:old, :new) ");
          q.setParameter("old","OldName");
          q.setParameter("new","NewName");
          int result = q.executeUpdate();
          session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
     };
```

And database stored procedure change_name which do update of name of client.. every time I run test I have one record with old name ?? I expect that update is execute in same transaction and that I never see old name ?

Comment: The first thing you do is `session.save(kom);` and kom is set to *OldName* so you **do** have a client with this 'name'.

Comment: save() does NOT insert. It associates the object with the session. The insert query is executed at the next flush. So call flush explicitely before calling your stored proc.

Comment: @JB Nizet but if we call the flush, it means the code is executed in two transactions? if exception happens after the insert the record still there?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that at all. flush means execute all the update/insert/delete queries that you haven't executed yet because you prefer doing it as late as possible.

Comment: Thanks JB, with flush() before execute query I have expected.  There is problem that this must be called before and procedure which make modification in data base..

Comment: Hibernate normally detects that a flush is necessary when executing HQL or Criteria queries, because it knows which tables such queries use. But for a stored procedure, it can't do such a detection. Since your stored proc makes the state of the loaded entities obsolete, you should flush and clear the session anyway.

Answer (score 0):

JB Nizet has right answer..

*save() does NOT insert. It associates the object with the session. The insert query is executed at the next flush. So call flush explicitely before calling your stored proc. –  JB Nizet yesterday*

There is also FlushMode ... I set to ALWAYS. I call many procedures which change data in database..